# How to RAW print a function?

Tags: php, bash, apache

I have a php module (.so) who has a function called `do_something()`.

When you execute this function on a browser it tells you can only use it on the command line.
If I run this function on the command line a bash script is executed.
Is there any way I can grab the SOURCE of this bash script?

Let's make an example.

```
<?php
    //foo.php
    do_something();
?>
```

If I run `php foot.php` a bash script is executed.  I want the source file of this bash script.

I've tried with `php foot.php > script.txt` but it only prints the STDOUT of the script.

I think that for working around it I need to wrap the **do_something()** function inside some other php function for printing the **raw** function.

Comment: So `do_something` is a function that shells out to `bash` and runs some script (the path to which is presumably hardcoded into the C code that was compiled into your `.so` file)?